# How to use the roots of equations?

Tags: equation-solving

Can anyone explain to me how can I use the roots of an equation? Let clarify my question with one example. Suppose that I have an equation which I want to find its root:

```
x^3=0.01 x
```

Now, I solve the equation in order to find the roots.

```
NSolve[x^3==0.01x, x]
```

We know that the answer is a list. I used the command 'Part' to pick the first root.

```
Part[NSolve[x^3==0.01x, x],1]
```

Now, I want to put this root in another function such as:

```
f[x_]:=x^2
```

This is the result of my code:

```
f[Part[NSolve[x^3==0.01x, x],1]]
{(x -> -0.1)^2}
```

As you see the answer is not a number. But, I need a number. How can I use the roots of equations in any other calculations?

Thanks a lot.

---

I used the code, and it pretty works well. But, unfortunately, it doesn't work for the following case:

```
v = NSolve[1 == E^(-(x/2))/x, x, Reals];
f[q_] := q;
f[q] /. v[[1]]
```

The output is:

```
{q}
```

It expect to get a number. What is happening?

Comment: If you really want to just get the first solution, without using substitution rules, you can get it with `NSolve[x^3 == 0.01 x, x][[1, 1, 2]]`.

Comment: Mehrdad, about your additional question, see edit in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Solve` routine gives you a substitution rule

```
solution = NSolve[x^3==0.01x, x]
```

> {{x -> -0.1}, {x -> 0.}, {x -> 0.1}}

which you can substitute into other expressions like

```
f[x_]:=x^2
```

by using the substitution operator `/.`

```
f[x] /. solution
```

> {0.01, 0., 0.01}

The above gives you a list of all three solutions. If you only want the first one, you can take the first part also by doing

```
f[x] /. solution[[1]]
```

> 0.01

In general, you can write any substitution rules you like, e.g.:

```
a/.a->b
```

> b

**EDIT**

In your code

```
v = NSolve[1 == E^(-(x/2))/x, x, Reals];
f[q_] := q;
f[q] /. v[[1]]
```

you are essentially trying to do a substitution like `q/.x->something`. So Mathematica is looking for any `x` it can find in the expression `q` and substitutes them by `something`. `q` is not `x` though, so naturally nothing happens. To get what you want, you can try

```
f[x] /. v[[1]]
```